# firefox tab crashing while browsersync reload css

Tags: firefox, gulp, browser-sync

I'm using gulp for a `wordpress` theme development serve by `mamp pro`.
Here is my `gulpfile.js` :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
     proxy: "http://favre.test",
     port:8080
  })
});
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
        css: './',
        sass: 'assets/sass',
        image: 'assets/img'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'compass'], function (){

    gulp.watch('assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['compass']); 
});
```

As you can see `browserSync` with a proxy reload `css` when a `*.scss` file is changing after compass.

It works fine but `firefox` tab crashing when `css` is reloaded. Working on chrome but i was wondering why `firefox`is crashing I something wrong in Gulp ?

Thanks for your answers. Don't hesitate to ask me questions if something is not clear. (french guy)

Comment: Resolved, apparently crashing because of "Grease monkey plugins" for firefox and a javascript script for anti-adblock killer. Works when Grease Mokey is disabled.

Comment: use violentMonkey -- I had the same problem